# Proof Clarification: A Compact Subset $A$ of a Hausdorff Space $X$ is Closed in $X$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

I have a problem with the following proof (specifically, the part in blue):

> **Theorem.** *A compact subset $A$ of a Hausdorff space $X$ is closed in $X$*
> *Proof.* To show that $\mathscr{C}A$ is open, we prove that each fixed $x_0\in \mathscr{C}A$ has a nbd lying in $\mathscr{C}A$. For each $a\in A$, find disjoint nbds $U(a)$, $U_a(x_0)$. Since $\color{blue}{\{U(a)\cap A\mid a\in A\}\text{ is an } \underline{\text{open}} \text{ covering}}$ of $A$, reduce it to a finite covering $U(a_1)\cap A, \dots , U(a_n)\cap A$; then $U(A)=\bigcup_1^n U(a_i)$ and $U(x_0)=\cap_1^n U_{a_i}(x_0)$ are disjoint open sets.

*In this text (Topology, James Dugundji) a nbd (read neighborhood) of a point $x$ was defined as any open set containing $x$.*

What makes $\mathfrak{A}:=\{U(a)\cap A\mid a\in A\}$ a family of open sets? For $\mathfrak{A}$ to be a family of open sets, one must have that $\forall a\in A,\; U(a)\cap A$ is open. Since $A$ is not necesarily open (in fact, we are trying to show its closed), how can we make such statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U(a)\cap A$ need not be open in $X$ but it is open **in  the relative topology of $A$**. Any open cover of $A$ by relatively open sets has  finite subcover so  the proof works.

Comment: Does anyone know how this important user is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Since $U(a)$ is an open subset of $X$, $U(a)\cap A$ is an open subset of $A$, by the definition of subspace topology.